# Debug Database.getQueryLocator(query);

Tags: apex

I want to see the result which `Database.getQueryLocator(query)` is returning in 'open execute anonymous window' so how to debug to see the result coming in that.

```
global database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Just simply run this query in **anonymous window** and you will get the result. Check code sample below.

```
string query = 'Select id from account';
system.debug(Database.getQueryLocator(query));
//add code to display the result.
Database.QueryLocator q = Database.getQueryLocator(s);
// Get an iterator
Database.QueryLocatorIterator it =  q.iterator();

// Iterate over the records
while (it.hasNext())
{
    Account a = (Account)it.next();
    System.debug(a);
}
```

Replace query with your query string.

Comment: Good one.. I was bit confuse what should I reply to this question. :-)

Comment: Or we can can directly write:
system.debug('Result of query----'+Database.query(query));

Comment: @Vinod Yes we can. But OP is asking for `Database.getQueryLocator(query)`